# Find a match on a line, delete that line and the line before that

Tags: bash, unix

I have a file with text as below,

```
ukncsavix302:  
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.6 (Santiago)  
ukncsavix353:  
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5 (Santiago)  
uknwsavix354:  
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5 (Santiago)
```

Now I need to find the lines with "6.5" on it, delete that line and delete one line above it.

Can someone help me break this?

Comment: Who on earth has upvoted this. Try the search function...

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
tac file.txt | sed -e '/6.5/,+1d' | tac
```

Output to new file if needed:

```
tac file.txt | sed -e '/6.5/,+1d' | tac > newfile.txt
```